# Synonym for backtrack

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The live CD Backtrack was »renamed« to Kali Linux. There is a tag [backtrack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backtrack) on the main site. I'd suggest to add a synonym [kali](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali) for questions on Kali.

Comment: There has been some [discussion](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/1380/5405) on this before. It was also suggested to use [tag:kali-linux].

Comment: Done! Just Created the synonyms....